# FirebaseError: Function setDoc() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[OrderDetails Logged image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dR52G.png)

I want to save order details to my firestore db,Here my orderDetails:

```
const orderDetails=[{
                      id:"ID1",
                      name:"foo"
                     },
                     {
                     id:"ID2",
                     name:"foo-foo"
                     },
                     ]
```

Here is the code for adding this order Details to fire store:

```
 .then(({paymentIntent})=>{
  if(user){
    console.log(basket);
    const userRef=doc(db,'shopDB',user.uid);
    const userOrderRef=doc(userRef,'userOrderInfo',paymentIntent.id);
    setDoc(userOrderRef,{
      orders: basket,
      created :paymentIntent.created,
      amount :paymentIntent.amount
   },{merge:true})
```

Here all working if i set document without orderDetails,Other two values will added to fire store,but when i try to add orders to database it throws error

error>>>>>>>>>>>

```
 FirebaseError: Function setDoc() 
 called with invalid data. Unsupported
 field value: undefined
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(orderDetails)` have checked if it is defined?

Comment: yes its defined

Comment: Can you share a screenshot... ? It could be any value in that object is undefined.

Comment: I think there is some way of adding array of objects to firestore but i didnt get that,I tried arrayUnion() but that is also not working

Comment: Is `userOrderRef` = `doc(database,collection,document)`?

Comment: yes bro without that object all are working fine

Comment: Could you please include the full code so that we can reproduce your encountered error.

Comment: I modified the post with full code

Comment: As pointed out by @gil, you have an undefined value on your object `alternative: undefined` at element in index 1.

Comment: Yes bro now it's solved

Answer (score 1):

looks like 1 of the 2 missing:

1. orderDetails is undefined
2. userOrderRef is undefined

try printing them both to make sure what's missing there

Edit:

now that I can see your console.log, your issue is with field alternative:undefined at element in index 1 according to your photo.
remove this property before trying to save it on firestore

Comment: I modified the post with an image please take a look

Comment: your issue is with field alternative:undefined at element in index 1  according to your photo